# Open multiple directories in different tabs in the same window in CentOS

Tags: centos, directory, nautilus

How can I set my CentOS to be able to open multiple directories in different tabs in the same window?

I have already enabled the feature to open the folders in the same window, but this is different: I would like to be able to open as many tabs I want for different folders.

Unfortunately, I don't know my graphical environment, since:

```
[user@maxipub9 extractions]$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
default
```

Comment: Use Terminator it gives you multiple windows
refer this site -> http://www.ubuntugeek.com/terminator-multiple-gnome-terminals-in-one-window.html

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Nautilus or in gnome-terminal?

Comment: Right I had to specify: in Nautilus.

Comment: check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) script with the --continue option, you can prepare the folder with symlinks to the tabs folders, and a new nautilus window will be opened, and all tabs will be opened also shortly after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both CentOS and Fedora make use of GNOME for their desktop environments. To open multiple tabs you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to add additional tabs.

[image: ss of tabs]

If you're attempting to have Nautilus open these tabs pre-populated with specific directories this, to my knowledge, is not possible. You'll have to resort to a scripted method such as this one from this AU Q&A titled: [open nautilus as new tab in existing window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55656/open-nautilus-as-new-tab-in-existing-window). Specifically the answer that shows the technique using `xdotool` along with `wmctrl`.

However the tabs feature was only made available in version GNOME 2.24 or higher. Looking at CentOS 5.10 it comes with Nautilus 2.16.

[image: ss of naut]

This article from ArsTechnica titled: [GNOME file manager gets tabbed file browsing](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2008/05/gnome-file-manager-gets-tabbed-file-browsing/) discusses the addition of this feature. So you're out of luck in using tabs with this particular version of Nautilus.

> This feature will likely be ready to roll for GNOME 2.24, which is scheduled for release in September. Another long-awaited Nautilus feature that is planned for GNOME 2.24 is the compact column view. A lot of other work has been done to iron out the remaining GVFS regressions.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Unfortunately, my desktop environment is really different from your picture. I don't have an address bar, nor the 'Ctrl + T' combination works to open multiple tabs. The second part of your answer I do not understand (about the pre-populated...).

Comment: @Py-ser - what version of CentOS? `cat /etc/redhat-release` will tell you this.

Comment: 'CentOS release 5.10 (Final)'

Comment: @Py-ser - see updates.

Comment: @Py-ser - I was surprised since I thought I had used tabs on my CentOS box before but then I remembered I would open multiple Nautiluses.

Comment: It sux so much, that one tends to forget :)

Comment: there is a better way, still with xdotool, but using ctrl+shift+t, check [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/566452/46437)